# How to change repository user privileges via Bitbucket API 2.0?

Tags: bitbucket

I'm looking for option to change repository user privileges via API 2.0. But at tutorial I find only option for API 1.0 wich is deprecated - https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/groups-endpoint-296093143.html. When I looking through documentation for API 2.0 I found only GET request's is it mean that nowaday there is no working solulution to change permition/privileges/grant via API 2.0?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User groups can no longer be managed using REST API 2.0. There is no available workaround as of this moment.

https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/deprecation-notice-v1-apis/?_ga=2.181452386.417879656.1531244294-1231042520.1527887148

https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/16556/no-api-support-for-groups-in-v2